# ShareKit text message doesn't align "New Message" bar with status bar

Tags: ios, sms, statusbar, sharekit

I have an app that hides the status bar. When I trigger the SHKTextMessage SMS controller, I find that, unlike the SHKMail object, it puts a status bar on the screen as it pops up the message display. This would be ok, except that I see the following screen:

[image: The Red is the view *behind* the message view that is showing because apparently the "New Message" bar is placed as if there were no status bar.]

When I tap the white plus button to select a send target and then immediately cancel it, it fixes itself, like this:

[image: fixed]

Is there something I can do to either suppress the status bar entirely (like the SHKMail seems to), or keep the New Message bar from aligning wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer why the problem occurs in the first place, but I find that I can remedy the problem at least by hiding the status bar after presenting the share kit text message controller like this:

```
[SHKTextMessage shareItem:item];

// fix strange status bar bug where it shows up in sms and offsets "New Message" bar weird
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```